# Trouble with HTML5 audio loop

Tags: javascript, html, audio, loops

I'm having trouble getting HTML5 audio to loop on my website: http://oclock.webs.com.
(It's an alarm which, when the alarm goes off, is supposed to loop a 1 second alarm sound over and over until you click OK on the alert box).

---

Simply including "loop" in the audio tag wasn't doing anything.

I found a helpful post on StackOverflow which lead me to this website: http://forestmist.org/2010/04/html5-audio-loops/

I knew Method 1 and 2 wouldn't work for me since they don't work on Firefox and are iffy on Chrome, and so Method 3 should have worked, unfortunately it didn't.  Method 3 works when I'm on that website's page, but not when the code is included in my own page so I think there may be some conflicting code.

---

Relevant part of my webpage:

```
<audio id="audio1" preload>
    <source src="media/alarm.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="media/alarm.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

<audio id="audio2" preload>
    <source src="media/alarm.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="media/alarm.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Relevant Javascript of the page:

```
if(timer==true && hours==hv && mins==mv && secs==sv){
    document.getElementById("audio1").play();
    alert("o'clock: Alarm ringing!");
    document.getElementById("alarm").value="Set Alarm";

    document.getElementById('audio1').addEventListener('ended', function(){
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.pause();
        document.getElementById('audio2').play();
    }, false);

    document.getElementById('audio2').addEventListener('ended', function(){
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.pause();
        document.getElementById('audio1').play();
    }, false);
}

else{
    document.getElementById("audio1").pause();
    document.getElementById("audio2").pause();
    document.getElementById("audio1").currentTime = 0;
    document.getElementById("audio2").currentTime = 0;
}
```

Intention: Upon the computer's time matching that of the selected time on the page, the audio alarm will repeat (loop) until the user clicks OK on the alert box popup.

Problem: Currently it only plays through the audio once, it doesn't loop.  Where did I mess up?

Comment: it would also help us if you could align your braces well.

Comment: Thanks @KyelJmD, added some intending.

Answer (score 0):

"ended event" or "loop" property dose not work on some browsers.
So I used window.setInterval() for looping audio playing.

For this method, you should know play time of Audio file in advanced.

```
function playAudioWithLoop (/**HTMLAudioElement*/audio, /**Number*/length)
{
    function onEnd (){
        audio.play();
    }

    /* length is msec */
    if(length > 0) {
        audio.__timer = window.setInterval(onEnd, length);
    }
}

function stopAudioWithLoop (/**HTMLAudioElement*/audio)
{
    if(audio.__timer) {
        audio.__timer = window.clearInterval(audio.__timer);
    }
}
```

======================================================================

```
***playAudioWithLoop(document.getElementById("audio1"), 12*1000);***
***stopAudioWithLoop(document.getElementById("audio1"));***
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to implement this and edit it.

Am I expected to replace current code with this, or this goes in addition to what I currently have?

What exactly should I edit in your given code (if anything)?